# Rails 3 ActionDispatch scope options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-3, actiondispatch

Do you know a resource which documents all the available options for the ActionDispatch [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-scope) method and their usage?

I'm quite tired of digging into each [merge_X_scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html) method trying to understand the X option implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long time, I found the solution. The options for Rails 3.1 are now described in the [mapper.rb file](http://rdoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base%3amatch).

[**Here is the documentation**](http://rdoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base%3amatch)